# SharePoint Online Default Document Library vs Document Library Created From App

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I am puzzled as to how the interface for the system-generated documents library is different from document libraries I create from the Document Library app.

The system-generated document library offers these three ribbon tabs: Browse, Files, Library. The extra document libraries I create using the Document Library app do not.

Image Description: The top library labeled "Documents" is the system-generated library. It has a ribbon. The bottom library is one I created to add to the site. It lacks the ribbon. The blue boxes redact the client name.

What am I failing to do when I create these libraries so that they each have a ribbon?